# How to check state and execute function after some delay in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout

I am trying to execute a function if the state doesn't change which is updated due to database fetch. I mean:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
const func = () => {
  ...
}

setTimeout(()=>{
  if(!value) {
     func()
  } else {
    // Alert.alert("Nothing!")
     funcWithoutDbOperations() // which is desired
  }
},20000)

fetchData.then(()=>setValue(true))
```

But this timeout method takes the initial state of the const `value`, and executes due to its initial value, not depending its value after 20 seconds. Even if it updates to `true`.

How can I achieve this object?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  I wonder if this might be an [XY problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: You can't!  React will only change the value of `value` when the component is re-rendered, it's defined as a const to hint at this behavior and to remind you that it won't change.  your previous setTimeout will never have the updated value in scope.

Comment: @James Isn't there a way to achieve this scenario in React? I mean the timeout method using the updated value coming from data fetch? There is a setState after response, therefore shouldn't it be rerendered?

Comment: You'd need to use a ref. You'll have to do some additional work to keep the ref in sync with the state value, but the ref should be accessible within the closure as its most up-to-date value `ref.currentTarget`

Comment: What behavior are you after?  fetch the data then call func?  fetch the data then wait 20 seconds then call func?

Comment: @James The func has some update operations from db. I am trying to keep the read/update functions from db as minimum as possible, therefore trying to wait for 20 seconds before read/update due to the response. I mean wait for 20 seconds in both scenarios. Can you give an example usage of ref regarding states?

Comment: @BrianThompson Can you give an example usage of ref regarding states? Maybe as an answer to this topic?

Comment: @JeremyFc Does this pen answer your question? https://codepen.io/sandstone991/pen/ExJPYgR
if so please reply so I can write up an answer for you, if not could you illustrate?

Comment: @SandStone This solution blocks all pending timeouts, so not the exact solution that I want. I am now trying plsdev89's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78117067/20742532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ref.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
const valueRef = useRef(value)
valueRef.current = value;

const func = () => {
  ...
}

setTimeout(()=>{
  if(!valueRef.current) {
     func()
  } else {
    // Alert.alert("Nothing!")
     funcWithoutDbOperations() // which is desired
  }
},20000)

fetchData.then(()=>setValue(true))
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I am not trying to execute func after state update. Can you read again my question please?

Comment: @JeremyFc You need to use Ref.

Comment: Thnx, this is the better solution then clearing timeout method